# Given days more than a week, month or year

Tags: javascript

if for example my 2 dates are only 5 days apart, I want to display `5 Days Ago`.

However if they are 12 days apart, I would display `1 week ago`.

And if they where around 29 days apart, I would display `1 Month Ago`.

However, different months have different amount of days in, so my below code won't work, how would I go about doing this?

What I have so far:

```
switch(true) {
  case (diff == 0):
    difference = 'Today';
  break;
  case (diff < 7):
    difference = diff + 'day' + (diff > 1 ? 's' : '') + ' ago';
  case;
  case (diff >= 7):
    difference = (diff / 7) + 'week' + ((diff / 7) > 1 ? 's' : '') + ' ago';
  break;
  case (diff >= 28) 
  break;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. You want 29 days to become "1 Month Ago" but only in February? Or because it's almost 1 month? Or say "1 Month Ago" when it happened the previous month, even if it was 1 day ago?

Comment: Just put a limit on it. Anything difference higher than 27? 28? becomes a month. Your code as written should work no? Besides, it doesn't matter. SInce you're counting the difference between two days, it doesn't matter if those days are in feb or in aug. If the problem is counting how many days are between two dates, convert them all to miliseconds past 1970, subtract and divide.

Comment: First define *in English* how long "a month" is. Then implement in code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [**momentjs**](https://momentjs.com/) with `relative time` so you don't have to worry about this hard problem yourself:

```
moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 5 years ago
moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 5 years ago
moment().startOf('day').fromNow();        // 13 hours ago
moment().endOf('day').fromNow();          // in 11 hours
moment().startOf('hour').fromNow();       // 26 minutes ago
```

Comment: This assumes of course that the OP is allowed to use 3rd party extensions for this project.

Comment: @Oriol - people apparently really love momentjs :P

Comment: @Lix if the op don't know how to use that, he can ask or search answers again XD

Comment: @xale94 - re-worded my comment a little bit - I did not mean that the OP doesn't know *how* to use it. Only that they might not be allowed to include external code in their project.

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be the best option.